# Are there any conditions where an event will not get unregistered?

Tags: c#, events

I am registering for an event in the constructor...

_data.WeldDataEvent += WeldDataEvent;

and unregistereing in a Cleanup() method called by Page Unloaded event...

_data.WeldDataEvent -= WeldDataEvent;

I have set a breakpoint at each location and when I startup the view, it only gets registered once. and at close it gets unregistered.

BUT, after the 2nd start, I now get 2 events fired. 
after 3rd start, I now get 3 events fired.

Are there any conditions where an event will not get unregistered?
Is there a way to verify the event is unregistered?

**Followup**
Using ANTS Memory profiler, there are no holdout references to my ViewModel or View...so I know they are getting garbagecollected...ie...no events are unregistered...

Comment: Is this an ASP.Net application?

Comment: No, just a standard class library... I am using Ninject and MVVMLight, but didn't see why that would matter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out through a simulation class I was creating a new simulator each time it was closed and restarted. The events were real.